# В свою очередь - нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Руководствоваться в работе нужно программами сотрудничества, в свою очередь(,) разработанными Министерством образования".

В ином случае я бы поставила здесь запятую, но ставится ли она в данном случае - если "в свою очередь" входит в причастный оборот?

Comment: А нужен ли вообще этот оборот? Вне контекста смысл неясен и оборот кажется лишним.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. В СВОЮ ОЧЕРЕДЬ стоит в начале обособленного оборота.